# How can I create a space after a table row with itextsharp?

Tags: c#, itext

I have a very simple itextsharp table like this:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Header spanning 3 columns"));
cell.Colspan = 3;
cell.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
table.AddCell(cell);
table.AddCell("Col 1 Row 1");
table.AddCell("Col 2 Row 1");
table.AddCell("Col 3 Row 1");

// Create spacing after row here only.

table.AddCell("Col 1 Row 2");
table.AddCell("Col 2 Row 2");
table.AddCell("Col 3 Row 2");
doc.Add(table);
```

How can I create a space between row 1 and row 2 only?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you want to add blank row as i understand please:
**Try this:**

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Header spanning 3 columns"));
cell.Colspan = 3;
cell.HorizontalAlignment = 1; //0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right
table.AddCell(cell);
table.AddCell("Col 1 Row 1");
table.AddCell("Col 2 Row 1");
table.AddCell("Col 3 Row 1");

PdfPCell cellBlankRow = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" "));
cell.Colspan = 3;
cell.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
table.AddCell(cellBlankRow);
table.AddCell("");
table.AddCell("");

table.AddCell("Col 1 Row 2");
table.AddCell("Col 2 Row 2");
table.AddCell("Col 3 Row 2");
```

Just insert blank rows using `Phrase`. I have tested and works fine..! If i am misunderstand please let me know..!

Comment: This is the correct answer (hence my up-vote), except for some minor details. (1.) You're setting the colspan to 3, but you are adding 3 cells. This isn't necessary. (2.) I would fine-tune the example by setting the fixed height of `cellBlankRow`, e.g.: `cellBlankRow.FixedHeight = 20;` where 20 equals a distance of 20 points.

Comment: yes @BrunoLowagie i agree..! :) and yes we can have just 3Empty table.AddCell("") rows..!

Answer (score 0):

```
        table.Add(new Phrase("\n", new iTextSharp.text.Font(
                    iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA,
                    4f,
                    FONT.NORMAL)));
```

You can add this 'new line' to your document too: 'document.Add(new Phrase("\n"..., where the 'document' is an iTextSharp Document instance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to add new line

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Header spanning 3 columns"));
cell.Colspan = 3;
cell.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
table.AddCell(cell);
table.AddCell("Col 1 Row 1");
table.AddCell("Col 2 Row 1");
table.AddCell("Col 3 Row 1");

//For blank line
 PdfPCell blankCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(Chunk.NEWLINE));
 blankCell.Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER;
 table.AddCell(blankCell);


table.AddCell("Col 1 Row 2");
table.AddCell("Col 2 Row 2");
table.AddCell("Col 3 Row 2");
doc.Add(table);
```